# Get parent Node in XML file in java

Tags: java, xml

i have the following XML file :

```
<table1>
<row0>
    <column1>String</column1>
    <column2>int</column2>
</row0>

<row1>
    <column1>aa</column1>
    <column2>65432</column2>
</row1>

<row2>
    <column1>ww</column1>
    <column2>1111</column2>
</row2>

<row3>
    <column1>fff</column1>
    <column2>333</column2>
</row3>

<row4>
    <column1>jj</column1>
    <column2>2</column2>
</row4>
```

and if i have for example the value aa i want to get "row1" as a String what should i do?

Comment: What you have tried ?  post some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the `column1` Element with the value **aa** and just want to get the name of the parent node, use **`col1Element.getParentNode().getNodeName()`**.